# Do I have to watch and compile sass to css in order to use it in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, sass, node-sass

I just started a project with Vue and I want to make of Sass. I have done everything needed to set Sass globally but seems vue isn't recognizing the sass files. Do I have to watch and then compile sass to css in order to make it work?

- I installed Node-sass and vue-loader
- Set up the vue.config.js

But whenever I start up Vue server,I get an error message saying the variables I set in the sass files are not defined, of which I defined them in the _variables.scss

This is the Vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
 css: {
      loaderOptions: {
           sass: {
                additionalData: `
                @import "@/assets/sass/abstracts/_mixins.scss";
                @import "@/assets/sass/abstracts/_variables.scss";
                @import "@/assets/sass/base/_base.scss";
                @import "@/assets/sass/layouts/_sidebar.scss";
                `
           }
      }
 }
```

}

I got the following error :-

```
 error  in ./src/components/SideBar.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=3eca7188&lang=scss

Syntax Error: SassError: Undefined variable: "$color-main".
        on line 10 of src/components/SideBar.vue
>>   background: $color-main;

   --------------^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using vue-cli or vite, you don't have to do anything but just consuming scss.

In case of importing variables in all sfc, https://css-tricks.com/how-to-import-a-sass-file-into-every-vue-component-in-an-app/ follow this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My vue.config.js was placed in the workspace folder instead of the vue project folder. everything is fixed now.